# Grab data referenced with Primary/foreign key relationships and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database that has two tables

1. dbo.Product

[image: Product Table]
[image]

2. dbo.Orders

[image: Order Table]

And the data it contains

[image: dataProduct]

I have a foreign key in dbo.Orders of ProductID that references ProductID in dbo.Product. The relationship diagram looks like this

[image: Relationship]

Ultimately what I want to do is have a drop down list that populates with the different product names. When you select a product name, It will show you which orders contain that ProductID by alterting the text of a label I have on my aspx page.

Here is how I populate the drop down

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateDropDown();
}
public void PopulateDropDown()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Product]", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]));
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader ddlValues;
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    showOrders.DataSource = ddlValues;
    showOrders.DataValueField = "ProductName";
    showOrders.DataTextField = "ProductName";
    showOrders.DataBind();

    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Dispose();


}
```

When I wanted to do something like this before, I used an INNER JOIN. However, I'm confused about whether I need to use that statement again. When I used INNER JOIN, I didnt need to have a foreign key to primary key relationship between the two tables. Can someone please explain to me what I need to do to achieve what I am after? Is it the same process as when I did it before? If so, why do I even need to create relationships at all?

Here is my ASPX Page

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="showOrders" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="showOrders_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="showContainingOrders" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes just do an inner join. Foreign key constraints enforce referential integrity so you can't for example have an `Order.ProductId = 5` if there is no `Product.ProductId=5`.

Comment: So the foreign key relationship doesnt help me in any way to relate the two tables on my web app? Sorry if these questions seem obvious. I'm quite new to this.

Comment: It helps you in that it ensures you cannot insert data with invalid relationships. It doesn't help you retrieve that data as such if you are just using ADO.net and SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks. If you put that in the form of an answer I will accept it.